# How to get indirectly assigned objects?

Tags: django, django-models

I have models:

```
class Model_1(models.Model):
    ...

class Model_2(models.Model):
    m1 = models.ManyToManyField(Model_1,...
    ...

class Model_3(models.Model):
    m2 = models.ManyToManyField(Model_2,...
    ...
```

and I have pk of model_3 object. How to get all model_1 objects which are indirectly assigned to the model_3?

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serves me, this should do what you need.

```
model_1_objs = Model_3.objects.get(pk=the_pk).m2_set.only('m1')
```